GCP call cloud function from another cloud function without waiting it to complete
I would like to call cloud function from another cloud function and get response that it has started successfully and do not wait until called cloud function is finished.
Current script calls cloud function successfully, but it waits for cloud function to be finished
url         = f"https://europe-west1-{PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/test_function"
auth_req    = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
id_token    = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, url)
auth_header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {id_token}"}
jsonData    = json.dumps(file_info)
response = requests.post(url, json = jsonData, headers=auth_header)
print(response)
return "File load triggered"


This sort of thing is not typically implemented with HTTP type functions.  You should instead implement a pubsub function and trigger it by sending it a message.

Either you use an async service like PubSub or Cloud Task, you use an async service, like Cloud Run job.

As others said it is not the best practice to use functions this way.
You may achieve this by using aiohttp and asyncio packages and call the second function in an async way.
https://www.pythonrequests.com/python-requests-async-await/
